# Breezing Forms Joomla- Japanese content displayed as question marks(?)

Tags: joomla, breezingforms

I'm using Breezing forms and building a Japanese website..All the contents are displayed in Japanese except for the select boxes and check boxes which display ???? instead of characters..
Please Help 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you not think your question would best be aimed at the Breezing Forms developer?

Comment: Got it done..Change content at the database level